# Why is const slower than var?

Tags: javascript, performance, constants, var, variable-declaration

I was testing performance differences between `const` and `var` in Javascript, when I noticed that `const` is slower than `var`.

I wrote a script to time `const` and `var` and compare them. It tests if `const` is faster 1000 times. `const` is faster only about 13% of the time.

```js
function executionTime(code) {
  var t0 = performance.now()
  code()
  var t1 = performance.now()
  return t1 - t0
}

function test() {
    
  var results = [0, 0] // one, two - Which one is faster?
    
  for (var i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
    var one = executionTime(function() {
      const x = 'x'
    })

    var two = executionTime(function() {
      var x = 'x'
    })
        
    if (one > two) {
      results[0]++
    } else {
      results[1]++
    }
  }
    
  return ((results[0] < results[1]) ? 'Const is slower': 'Var is slower') + ' - const was faster ' + results[0] + ' times, and var was faster ' + results[1] + ' times'
}

console.log(test())
```

So, my question is, why is a variable declaration with `var` faster than one with `const`?

Comment: Consider using an online microbenchmark tool (or even library and online fiddle). 1) More easily shareable/comparable 2) _Reduces_ microbenchmark bias. The timing method here looks flawed, given nothing else.

Comment: I run several tests here, the result varies and it's always less than 0.5%, so it seems there is no real difference https://jsben.ch/

Comment: Put up a link there to the different code so I (and others) can run it - any performance difference is an artifact of the implementation. When I ran a benchmark, the const was inconsequentially ‘faster’ (Safari iOS); 100 vs 99.8/9. However, with such small timed bodies and other overhead, I would not put much weight on the results.

Comment: I'd expect that both your codes are getting optimised away since they don't do anything [and you're measuring something else](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html). Also 1000 runs is too few for warming up the optimising compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I ran a few tests with [jsbench](https://jsben.ch), as suggested in the comments, I realized that the performance could vary, and that my timing method was flawed.

JSBench: https://jsben.ch/eAiAk

So, there is no real time difference between `const` and `var`.